# JFormattedTextField instead of JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

In Java, what is the difference between  `JTextField`  and `JFormattedTextField` ? 
I mean when should I use `JFormattedTextField` instead of `JTextField`?

Comment: When you want the text to be formatted beyond normal plaintext, like [this.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JFormattedTextField differs from JTextField in that it can support

- locale-specific display
- restrictions on its value
- editing non-Strings [via setValue(Object)/getValue()]
- incrementing/decrementing from the keyboard

To know more about it [Click here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation for `JFormattedTextField` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html), essentially it adds support for formatting arbitrary date values, so it'd would be beneficial when handling date entries

Answer (score 1):

`JTextField` is used for plain text.

`JFormattedTextField` is a class that extends from `JTextField` and it is used to set any format to the text that it contains (in example, phone numbers, e-mails, dates, etc.).

If you don't need to set any special format to the textfield, it's recommendend to use `JTextField`.